# Кто то знает библиотеку или модуль в pyrogram для изменения эмоджи статусов

Tags: python, telegram, pyrogram

***"Телеграм Premium, Функция Эмоджи статус"***

Хочу реализовать идею для автоматического изменения Эмоджи

Хочу сделать юзербота или простой скрипт, при помощи которого смогу через команду поменять Эмоджи на любой из подготовлених вариантов

Answer (score 1):

Есть такой метод, в доках указан

```
from pyrogram import types

await app.set_emoji_status(types.EmojiStatus(custom_emoji_id=1234567890987654321))
```

https://docs.pyrogram.org/api/methods/set_emoji_status#set-emoji-status